# JUnit5 check exception is thrown in thread

Tags: java, junit, concurrency, junit5

I have some service like this:

```
class SomeService{

    private final Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    void handle(SomeEvent event) {
        executor.execute(
                () -> {
                    //... logic omitted
                    if (isBadCase()) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Something bad happen");
                    } 
                    //... time consuming logic continued
                }
        );
    }

...

//other methods
}
```

And I want to test "badCase", that `RuntimeException("Something bad happen")` is thrown.
Is it possible to achieve using JUnit5?

For other cases "normal" or "notSoBad" I've implemented workaround which is just a wait cycle for some condition is met for corresponding case, like this:

```
private void awaitForNormalConditionIsMet(int seconds) {
        for (int step = 1; step <= seconds * 40; step++) {
            if (normalConditionIsMet()) return;
            else {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Waiting for condition - " + (step * 25) + "ms");
                    Thread.sleep(25);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        Assertions.fail();
    }
```

And this workaround works well when I have something corresponding to check.
But for the "badCase" nothing corresponding is changed, only the exception is thrown.

And I cannot extract the exception throwing logic from executor.
Could you please help?

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2596493/6413377) provides help.

Comment: The main point for me from this is - "The JUnit framework captures only assertion errors in the main thread running the test. It is not aware of exceptions from within new spawn threads."
So I will refactor the code then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to refactor code especially if your `Runnable` has more complex logic.

If you make it a separate **unit** to test you have more control with it. And testing is more easy, for example:

```
public class SomeService {

    private final Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    void handle(SomeEvent event) {
        executor.execute(new MyRunnable(event));
    }

    // This is inner non-static in my example class because isBadCase()
    // could be in service. Of course this isBadCase could be anywhere.
    public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        private SomeEvent event; 
        public MyRunnable(SomeEvent event) {
            this.event = event;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (isBadCase()) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Something bad happen");
            }                    
        }
    }

    public boolean isBadCase() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Now there is no problem with threads or so because you can catch the exception in main thread directly and at the same time you are doing more granular unit testing of your code:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class SomeServiceTest {

    // Spy is because you want to mock normal case for isBadCase = false
    // to true so causing the exception to be thrown
    @Spy
    private SomeService someService;
    
    @Test
    void testOk() {
       someService.new MyRunnable(new SomeEvent()).run();
    }

    @Test
    void testBadCase() {
        Mockito.when(someService.isBadCase()).thenReturn(true);
        MyRunnable myRunnable = someService.new MyRunnable(new SomeEvent());
        assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, () -> myRunnable.run());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @pirho. I think you are right. I have to refactor my code to make it more testable.