# AssertThrows doesn't catch Exception while calling the method throws the same Exception

Tags: java, multithreading, testing

Can anyone explain to me why, in this case, asserting that an Exception is thrown when a method is called doesn't seem to work because "*expected it.exceptions.SemaphoreException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown*" while calling directly the method cause the same exception to be thrown?

```
@Test
void concurrentBatchTest() {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_THREADS);
    for(int i=0; i < 1; i++) {
        Runnable worker = new RProcess();
        executor.execute(worker);
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
        // Assertion fails because nothing was thrown
        assertThrows(SemaphoreException.class, () -> drlScheduler.computeR());
        // Calling the method with the following line ends throwing SemaphoreException
        // drlScheduler.computeR();
    }
}

private class RProcess implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        drlScheduler.computeR();
    }
}
```

I can fix the problem using try-catch block calling directly the method but it's not as clear as asserting an Exception to be thrown.

Consider that *computeR()* is an extremely quick method, so the issue could be linked to the fact that asserting an exception to be thrown is slower than calling directly the method and in the first case, the Semaphore is already off when the method encounters it, does anyone have evidence of what I said or of the real reason behind this behavior?

Comment: When you call it directly, is it _always_ throwing that exception? As in, could you be going round the loop a few times before it throws?

Comment: It is always throwing the exception, the first instruction it does is checking whether the Semaphore is on or off, and when the method is called directly, it always finds it On.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason may be due to the fact that the exception is thrown on a different thread.

You create a runnable and execute its run method with `ExecutorService`, so when `worker` calls `dlrScheduler.computeR();` the exception is thrown on the remote thread, and JUnit can only capture exceptions thrown in the main thread (which explains why you can run `dlrScheduler.computeR();` directly in `concurrentBatchTest` method and assert the Exception was thrown).

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2596530/17105581) answer for a solution, hope it helps.